# Should I put this javascript code in a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript better. There is a lot I don't know, for example, I have this simple code, should it be in a function that calls it's self? Or should I leave it like this? And why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.some_ul_class').each(function(i, obj) {
        var childrenCount = $(this).find('li').length;
        $(this).addClass('li-count-' + childrenCount);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you plan to use that routine more than once it would be usefull to put things in a function. Reusability is the keyword ..

Comment: You can extract $(this) to local variable for better performance, but in most cases the gain will be negligible. All other looks perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions have two purposes in JavaScript:

- Controlling scope.
- Allowing code to be reusable.

You aren't creating any variables in the global scope, so there is no scope change by using a function.

That leaves allowing code to be reusable. Do you want to call that piece of code multiple times? If so, use a function.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I'm not a total JS noob, but every once in a while someone looks at your code and says "that's not the best way to do this", I was always curious if there are any other reasons other than re-usability, best practices of some kind.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me this use of jQuery looks ok.

However, I wouldn't choose to use jQuery to add classes in this way.

If the items in your jQuery selector are part of a list, the classes could/should be added by the server in the loop that created them in HTML.

To me the jQuery snippet introduces some magic that can be hard to debug later on.

Comment: A fine point about the classes :) sadly, they cannot be set by the back-end side in this particular case. But very good advice, thank you!